# Indentation and wrapping XML document with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, indentation, word-wrap

I'd like to format different XML documents, using a single XSLT stylesheet doc.
How can I do the following with XSLT:

1. Indentation of 3 space chars?
2. wrapping line after 100 chars?

The settings are not specific to a pre-defined token or node, but to the whole XML

Comment: You can use `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>` to achieve decent looking output, but it doesn't provide fine-level control over indentation levels or line widths.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is typically used to either change the structure or the content of documents. In most cases, indentation of elements in XML documents is purely cosmetical, since whitespace-only text nodes are usually not significant. That said, there is an effective method to properly indent any XML document, an *identity transform* that specifies `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`. Yet, the number of indentation characters will depend on the implementation of the XSLT processor you are using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

which will transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body><h1></h1></body>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <h1/>
</body>
```

You could produce a document that wraps text after a certain amount of characters, but this is usually not done with XSLT. XSLT transforms data, it is not meant to be used as a rendering agent. Line wrap is something that should be enforced within a tool that displays data, like an editor. Many editors have a line wrap option, for instance to make the document fit to the current window size.

So, to sum up, if indentation by a specific amount of spaces and line wrap are the only changes you'd like to make to a document, do not use XSLT. The former is impossible, the latter is nonsensical perhaps - except there is good reason to do it.

Comment: Hi,
1) Indentation of 3 space chars:
    you've suggested xalan transformer; Looks great but I need to run it in the client side. is there a javascript based tool?
2) wrapping line after 100 chars:
     I want to modify complete line which contains nodes (not just the text node).

Comment: @user1820248 I did not suggest Xalan, Michael did. Please comment on his answer, otherwise he will not be notified. By the way, please also read my answer...

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Indentation of 3 space chars?

If you are using the Xalan processor, you can set `xsl:output` to:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" xalan:indent-amount="3"/>
```

Otherwise it would be probably be best to set the output to:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

and let the processor apply the amount of indent it was programmed to apply.

--

In the (unlikely) case you **must** have an indent of exactly 3 spaces, you could perhaps try something along these lines:

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                                           '" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="indent" select="concat('&#10;', substring($spaces, 1, 3*count(ancestor::*)))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Obviously this needs more work (which I am not willing to put into it).

---

> 2. wrapping line after 100 chars?

I presume you mean text nodes? If done through XSLT, this would have to modify the actual text, thus it would fall outside the definition of "formatting".

Comment: Hi, 1) Indentation of 3 space chars: you've suggested xalan transformer; Looks great but I need to run it in the client side. is there a javascript based tool?
 2) wrapping line after 100 chars: I want to modify complete line which contains nodes (not just the text node).